# jUnit for file reader

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I got a method that read from a txt file and populate a list with words that are exists in the file.
the method is calculate and return Most Repeated Word.
If I want to write a jUnit for that. how should I test the corectess of that method given the fact the file is changing frequentaly.

Comment: To test you may know the number of occurence of the most repeated word, if not you cannot, so if the file change it's difficult ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jaibalaji wrote, JuintTests should not depend on resources outside of the JVMs memory.

So the first step must be to make your *code under test* (cut) independent of the actual file.

> I got a method that read from a txt file and populate a list with words that are exists in the file. the method is calculate and return Most Repeated Word.

In this sentences you mention 3 responsibilities:

1. reading a file
2. populating a list
3. find Most Repeated Word

You should split this  method so that you ed up with smaller classes with the one responsibility each only.

class TextAnalyser{
      private final WordListBulder wordListBulder; // converts String into List of words
      private final WordCountAnalyser wordCountAnalyser;
      public TextAnalyser(WordListBulder wordListBulder, WordCountAnalyser wordCountAnalyser){
          this.wordListBulder = wordListBulder;
          this.wordCountAnalyser = wordCountAnalyser;
      }

```
public String findMostRepeatedWordIn(MyFileReader myFileReader){
   String fileContent = myFileReader.readContent();
   List<String> wordList = wordListBulder.crerateWordListFrom(fileContent);
   return wordCountAnalyser.findMostRepeatedWordIn(wordList);
}
```

This code is *too simple to fail* and don't need to be UnitTested. *Module-* and/or *Acceptance-Tests* will show that this works.

Now the behavior to test is in the class `WordCountAnalyser`. And it has a simple t "fake" input which leads to a deterministic testable output.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be a parameter of the method or an instance field of the class of this method.
In this way, you can unit test the method by providing a file which you master the data and you know how assert them.

For example with the parameter way :

```
public String findMostRepeatedWork(File file){
    ...    
}
```

And so you could unit it easily :

```
@Test
public void findMostRepeatedWork(){
   // fixture
   File myTestFile = ...;
   // action
   new MyClassToTest.findMostRepeatedWork(myTestFile);
  // assertion
    ...
}
```

Comment: It should be one step further: The `BufferedReader` or `InputStream` should be the classes *dependency* so that we can create **mocks** of that interfaces and don't need to touch file system...

Comment: I wrote the method that return mostRepeatedWord. how do i know that I wrote it right in the first place?

Comment: @MaorShitrit You don't unless you wrote the UnitTest for each and every  expected behavior *before* the actual code (TDD)

Answer (score 0):

Junit is not intended for any test that is taking resources(file, dB or network)